# How to print multiple output lines together from awk

Tags: awk

I have an output which looks like

```
________________________________________________

 :: Method           : GET
 :: URL              : HOST/FUZZ
 :: Follow redirects : false
 :: Calibration      : false
 :: Timeout          : 10
 :: Threads          : 500
 :: Matcher          : Response status: 200
________________________________________________

[Status: 200, Size: 52, Words: 2, Lines: 6]
    * FUZZ: index.jsp
    * HOST: https://test.com
```

what I want from this output is only two things contact them together

Expected output

```
https://test.com/index.jsp
```

what I tried already is

```
awk '/HOST:/{ print $4} /FUZZ:/{ print $4}' ffuf'
```

output

```
index.jsp
https://test.com
```

Hexdump output

```
grep 'FUZZ:' ffuf | hexdump -C
```

Output

```
00000000  0d 0d 20 20 20 20 2a 20  46 55 5a 5a 3a 20 69 6e  |..    * FUZZ: in|
00000010  64 65 78 2e 6a 73 70 0a                           |dex.jsp.|
00000018
```

any idea how to contact them together?

thanks

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$3` instead of `$4` in your example?

Comment: nope. If I $3 the output was FUZZ: and HOST: only

Comment: There is  space in front of the asterisk

Comment: There must be some strange characters in the output, not only spaces or tabs.

Comment: I am not sure what it is. But $3 is not working

Comment: `awk` does by default delimit fields by runs of both spaces and tabs. There is no fourth field on the `HOST:` and `FUZZ:` lines.

Comment: I am not sure what's happing here but if I run awk with $3 its getting wrong output here. 

> awk '/FUZZ: /{print $3} /HOST:/{print $3}' file
FUZZ:
HOST:


> awk '/FUZZ: /{print $4} /HOST:/{print $4}' file
index.jsp
https://test.com

Comment: Add output of `grep 'FUZZ:' file | hexdump -C` to your question.

Comment: Added hexdump output

Comment: Those two `0x0d` characters at the start of the line are two carriage return characters.  These constitute the first field.  You should (or at least could) use `$NF` to get the last field of the line (as I've done in my answer).

Comment: got it thanks for the help.

Comment: Please take a look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `hexdump` output that you show, it's clear that there are two carriage return characters at the start of the lines containing the data that you're after.  These would constitute the first field on those lines if you parsed the data using `awk`.  Both variations (`sed` and `awk`) below work around this by either ignoring (`sed`) or avoiding (`awk`) these.

---

Using `sed`, and assuming that the line with `FUZZ:` always occurs before the line with `HOST:`:

```
$ sed -n '/.*FUZZ: /{ s///; h; }; /.*HOST: /{ s///; G; s,\n,/,p; }' file
https://test.com/index.jsp
```

The `sed` command (which is run with the default outputting of every line turned off with `-n`) matches the `FUZZ:` line and deletes everything on it up until the filename.  The filename is then copied to he hold space with `h`.

When the `HOST:` line is matched, the start of that line is likewise removed, and the contents of the hold space is appended to the URL (the remainder of the `HOST:` line).  The newline inserted by the `G` command is then changed to a slash and the resulting string is printed.

---

Using `awk`, with the same assumption as above:

```
$ awk -v OFS='/' '/FUZZ:/ { fuzz = $NF } /HOST:/ { print $NF, fuzz }' file
https://test.com/index.jsp
```

Here, the variable `fuzz` plays the role of the hold space that we used in the `sed` variation above, i.e. to hold the filename. `$NF` is the data in the last field on a line.

Comment: thanks, I understood your solution.

Answer (score -1):

I achieve this by doing

```
awk '/FUZZ:/{ FUZZ=$4; next } /HOST:/{ print $4 "/" FUZZ }'
```

**OUTPUT**

```
https://test.com/index.jsp
```

Comment: Unless you expect `HOST:` and `FUZZ:` occurring on the same line, there is no need for `next`. Also, there is no fourth field in your data, so `$4` will be empty.

Comment: $3 is not working with my output. When I use $3 it prints the HOST: and FUZZ: only not the data I want

Comment: Copy and paste the data from your question and try your solution on that. Also, follow the advice from Cyrus in comments to the question.

Comment: Added hexdump output as suggested. There might be some copy-paste mistake to output.

Comment: That line (and presumably all of them) starts with CR CR. Those are not treated as whitespace, so that is $1.